# Sens de l'expression « envoyer le maïs »

Tags: expressions, sens, argot

[Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2013/06/22/apres-l-agression-de-femmes-voilees-des-argenteuillais-denoncent-l-islamophobie_3434981_3224.html) cite un déséquilibré qui proclamait:

> « s'il y en a un qui passe sous ma fenêtre, je lui envoie le maïs ! »

Que signifie l'expression « envoyer le maïs » ?

Apparement la police a compris l'expression, et elle justifie une arrestation.
Est-ce une référence aux grenades à plâtre que le déséquilibré avait chez lui ?

Voir aussi:  [*envoyer la purée*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/envoyer_la_puree) et [*balancer la sauce*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/balancer_la_sauce).

Comment: Le "déséquilibré" ? Première fois que j'entends cette expression pour désigner quelqu'un d'un peu fou (ce que je suppose étant ce à quoi tu fais référence).

Comment: Ce n'est pas moi qui ai inventé, "déséquilibré" est le mot employé par Le Monde. Ce n'est pas un usage rare, et il semble convenir ici pour désigner un individu dangereux proférant des menaces de mort.

Comment: C'est un mot très courant en France. "Un déséquilibré" évoque sans ambiguïté ce type d'individus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je n'ai jamais entendu cela, et ne trouve rien de probant en recherchant sur internet:

- Google ngrams : "Ngrams not found: Envoyer le maïs" ([lien](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=envoyer%20le%20ma%C3%AFs,envoyer%20du%20bois,envoyer%20bouler,cracher%20des%20pruneaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=))
- Google trends : "Volume de recherche insuffisant pour afficher des graphiques" ([lien](http://www.google.fr/trends/explore?q=envoyer%20le%20ma%C3%AFs,envoyer%20du%20bois,envoyer%20bouler#q=envoyer%20le%20ma%C3%AFs,%20envoyer%20du%20bois,%20envoyer%20bouler,%20cracher%20des%20pruneaux&cmpt=q))
- Google Search : renvoie [ici même](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/sens-de-lexpression-envoyer-le-mais&ei=PhbIUbLYFqir0QXP9IGgDQ&usg=AFQjCNGeHSeKc-ODMiE4WWTJrqna7edAZg&sig2=xP98L0uGV6OZL5dcl60w1A&bvm=bv.48293060,d.d2k)
- Expressio, l'Internaute, le Dico des Mots, Reverso ne donnent rien non plus (on ne sait jamais, il fallait essayer)

Si j'entendais cette phrase, je penserais immédiatement que la personne va tirer au fusil de chasse, car les grains de maïs évoquent la chevrotine. J'imagine que c'est également ce que les policiers ont compris.

Plus largement, l'idée *d'envoyer quelque chose à quelqu'un par la fenêtre*, de la part d'une personne menaçante et retranchée chez elle, laisse supposer qu'elle va utiliser une arme et peu importe laquelle.

Quoiqu'il en soit, j'ai l'impression qu'*envoyer le maïs* n'est pas une expression idiomatique mais une simple image, une métaphore très spontanée.

Answer (score 6):

Il semble qu'il s'agit d'une expression partagée par un cercle restreint de personnes qui s'inspire de l'univers d'[Alphonse Boudard](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonse_Boudard).

> "Tiens voilà les poulets¹, je vais leur envoyer le maïs!"

... pour les nourrir au plomb.

<sup>ou *les flics* : les policiers en argot traditionnel , *les keufs* (argot contemporain)</sup>

Comment: Une référence à une œuvre particulière ?

Comment: Je rejoins l'interrogation de Stéphane... à quelle passage de quel livre ? Étonnant qu'une recherche Google sur ces mots ne donne rien.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez non, seulement un souvenir de vacances scolaires ou un correspondant anglais avait acheté du blé (pas possible ici, car il n'a pas le même sens argotique) et en jetait aux pieds des gendarmes qui faisait la circulation en appelant 'chicken, chicken'. Heureusement qu'à l'époque les pandore (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot) de province n'étaient pas anglophones.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression, mais elle est semblable à d'autres du même style qui me font comprendre: *tirer avec une arme à feu*.

Par exemple, dans *Sing-Sing song*, Claude Nougaro utilise: *ça crache des pruneaux*.

Je doute que la police ait compris juste par l'expression que l'individu détenait des grenades à plâtre.